# cannot implicitly convert string to int in C#

Tags: c#

In the below code  i have a datarow in which i am selecting the value from the datatable . and i want to hold the datarow value in a string.But it throws "cannot implicitly convert string to int".Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
MastersClient objDB1 = new MastersClient();
DataSet dsTemp = objDB1.Email(UserID);
DataTable Menu = new DataTable();
Menu = dsTemp.Tables[0];
DataRow[] rows = dsTemp.Tables[0].Select("[MenuName]= 'PNDIND'");

string item = rows["MenuName"].ToString();
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are confused with the DataRow Indexer and array indexer. DataRow has indexer that accepts the string index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying something like this, but you forgot to specify the row number:

```
//rowNumber is int
string item = rows[rowNumber]["MenuName"].ToString();
```

Or if you are going to get `MenuName` value for all rows:

```
string[] items = rows.Select(i=>i["MenuName"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @MVS glad to be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the string `"MenuName"` as an array index in the last line.  You can't do this; the index must be an integer.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, please don't edit my answer in a way that changes its meaning and correctness.

Comment: my edit didn't changed the meaning of your answer, it is suggested to show code portion and variables which are used in code between ` characters. Here is what I mean:

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: You changed a string literal, "MenuName", into a bareword, `MenuName`, which looks like an identifier.  There is no variable `MenuName` in the OP's code.

Comment: Yes it is not a variable but it is a **code portion**. Anyway I tried improve the formatting and you may don't like suggested style which is provided. You can see this suggestion when trying to edit any comment by clicking on the **help** link bellow the *Save Edits*

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, this isn't about formatting.  You removed the quotes around "MenuName", which changes it from a string literal to a bareword.  That fundamentally changed the meaning of my answer.  I've made an edit to mark `"MenuName"` as a code section to appease you while retaining the correctness of my answer.  Please do not further change the "formatting."